# Definition of "Scalar coextension"

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Let $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism. Here $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings. Suppose we have an $A$-module $M$, and we hope to construct a $B$-module. A traditional way is via *base change*, namely construct the module $M_B:= B \otimes_A M$. Then this is a $B$-module.

Yet in the posts

> MO 300531: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300531/adjoints-of-scalar-extension-and-scalar-coextension?rq=1

and

> MSE 2780723: [Induced representation: which adjoint is it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780723/induced-representation-which-adjoint-is-it)

People also constructed a $B$-module $M^B := \text{Hom}_A(B, M)$ and call this a **scalar coextension** (as in the math.SE post quoted above answered by @Qiaochu Yuan). My question is: **What is the $B$-module structure on $M^B$?** It is indeed an $A$-module, but I looked up many posts and books but have not found any definition of it. So could someone provide me with some references or give me the definition of it?

**My guess**: Let $f \in M^B := \text{Hom}_A(B, M)$ and $b \in B$, then the $A$-module homomorphism $b \cdot f$ is defined by sending any element $r \in B$ to $f(br)$. Is this definition correct? It seems that there should be a **correct definition**, since people usually regard (or define) this as the right adjoint to the functor of the restriction of scalars, i.e. view a $B$-module $N$ as an $A$-module via $\phi$, by defining $a \cdot x := \phi(a) \cdot x$ for any $a \in A$ and $x \in N$.

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: Coextension of scalars makes sense with no commutativity assumptions and then your guess is not correct; you should multiply on the right if you want a left module.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hanno Thank you for your comments!